# How to set header X-Content-Type-Options “nosniff” in Angular/SpringBoot application?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, security, x-content-type-options

i need to add X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff header in every response coming from my application any response from backend has this header already present but i want to add this header also with index.html and other file.

Comment: Please add more details to the question

Comment: I want to add X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff header in response from angular response is there a way? Please comment if any other detail require

Comment: So you want to add this header to Angular’s request or Spring Boot’s response?

Comment: in response header of Angular while serving index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved this by configuring headers from my spring boot application. Since our application was a single deployment application (frontend and backend in one build).

If you want to achieve something similar it could be done by configuring headers at the server level.